# Тире перед то же самое

Tags: пунктуация

Уместно ли поставить тире перед "то же самое": Этот термин - то же самое, что и бытующие термины...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тире ставится практически в обязательном порядке, так как сочетание  "то же самое" имеет предметное значение, то есть употребляется в значении существительного. (В таких случаях также часто используется связка ЭТО, но в данном предложении ее нельзя применить).

Примеры

Словосочетание «диктатура закона» ― это то же самое, что «жареный лед», то, чего в природе не существует.

Для Толстого говорить о нравственности, не упоминая имени Бога, ― то же самое, что говорить о теории всемирного тяготения, не упоминая имени И. Ньютона.

Хорошие модели для автомобильного рынка ― то же самое, что для обычного базара пирожки с вкусной начинкой: разлетаются мгновенно.

А поскольку медленно ездить на такой машине ― это то же самое, что стрелять из пушки по воробьям...

Для сравнения:

"Эксплуататор тот же самый ― капитал". В этом случае **нет тире перед признаковым сказуемым** ТОТ ЖЕ САМЫЙ, выраженным местоименным прилагательным.